I try to run pyspark on VS Code but facing the following error
Actually I try to initialize the pyspark session, but continuously I'm facing the following error:
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
PS D:\pr> SUCCESS: The process with PID 5160 (child process of PID 7380) has been terminated.
PS D:\pr> he process with PID 7380 (child process of PID 13032) has been terminated.
PS D:\pr> he process with PID 13032 (child process of PID 8268) has been terminated.

Although, I already set my environment and paths.
I'm trying to initialize the pyspark session on VS Code and my code is:

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Pyspark-Get-Started").getOrCreate()

But my pyspark session can't be initiallized.
